# Finding nodes with "missing" attributes

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml

I have xml that looks like this:

```xml
<Doc>
  <Thing>
      <ID type="One">Fred</ID>
   </Thing>
   <Thing>
      <ID>Bill</ID>
   </Thing>
   <Thing>
     <ID type="Two">John</ID>
   </Thing>
</Doc>
```

I can write LINQ to find the type="One" nodes.  (or type="Two")

```vb
Dim ThingList As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = _
   From el In doc...<Thing>.<ID> _
   Where el.Attribute("type").Value = "One" _
   Select el
```

How would I write a linq query to find the ID node that doesn't have a type attribute at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the fact that `Attribute()` will return null/nothing if there's no such attribute.

In C# I would use:

```
var idsMissingType = doc.Descendants("ID") // Or whatever
                        .Where(x => x.Attribute("type") == null);
```

My *guess* is that the VB you want is:

```
Dim ThingList As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = _
   From el In doc...<Thing>.<ID> _
   Where el.Attribute("type") Is Nothing _
   Select el
```